# Insert data into sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I'm insert data into sqlite database and I've seen NSLog(@"DONE") on my console result, but I don't see the data update in my sqlite database file. Pls help me !!!

Here my code to save data:

```
- (void)saveData:(NSString *)_Id
{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    NSString *_databasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.db"];

    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO MyTable (id) VALUES (\"%@\")", _Id];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt,
                           -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"DONE");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to add contact");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, go back and make sure you check ALL error codes.  And understand that about 99 times out of 100 your symptoms are due to the SQL file not being where you think it is.

Comment: (Use sqlite3 from the command line to examine your DB.)

Comment: @KhoaNN The reason you're seeing "DONE", but not seeing the results is probably because the bundle is read only. You have to copy db to Documents folder (if not there already) and then use that database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the database in your bundle. The bundle is read-only on the device. You must copy the database to your `Documents` folder (if it doesn't exist there already) and open it from there.

Also be aware that you're dealing with multiple copies of the database (the one in your project, the one in the bundle and now the one in the device/simulator's `Documents` folder). Make sure you're checking for the inserted record in the correct database (the one in `Documents`)

As an aside, you should also check to see that `sqlite3_prepare_v2` returned `SQLITE_OK` and if not, log `sqlite3_errmsg`.

You should also use `?` placeholder in your SQL and bind values using `sqlite3_bind_text` (or, if it's possibly `nil`, `sqlite_bind_null`):

```
- (void)saveData:(NSString *)_Id
{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.db"];
    NSString *documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *documentsPath = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.db"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath isDirectory:NO]) {
        NSError *error;
        if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:documentsPath error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"database copy failed: %@", error);
        }
    }

    const char *dbpath = [documentsPath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *insertSql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (id) VALUES (?)";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertSql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"prepare error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }

        // bind a value to the ? placeholder in the SQL

        if (_Id) {
            if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [_Id UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"bind text error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            }
        } else {
            if (sqlite3_bind_null(statement, 1) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"bind null error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            }
        }

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"DONE");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to add contact: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

Most people move that "if database doesn't exist in documents, then copy it from the bundle and open it from there" logic inside a dedicated `openDatabase` method, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did as you do but my database not update, and i still see "DONE" showing :(

Comment: @KhoaNN And are you looking at the database in the device/simulator's Documents folder (as opposed to the one in the bundle or in your project)?

Comment: I'm looking database in "/Volumes/DATA/KhoaNN/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/485F9F41-683F-44C7-9A63-A16FE5609853/MyApplication.app/data.db"

Comment: @KhoaNN That's the read-only database in the bundle. Go up a level and look in the Documents folder. The above code will create a copy of the database there, and your inserted record should be in that database.

Comment: Wow! I can looking my database with new record on Documents folder. Thank a lot @Rob !!!